# Contemplating is the Cartesian product of three integer sets is countably infinite or uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

I have been researching the countability of the Cartesian product of **three** integer sets (which are countably infinite sets).  Although I find information on the infinite countability of the cartesian product of two integer sets and the uncountability of the Cartesian product of infinite integer sets, I have yet to see anything on three sets.

Would the Cartesian product of three integer sets, therefore, fall under *infinitely countable*, like that of two integer sets, or would it be *uncountable*, like that of infinite sets?

Thanks for the insight, in advance! I am interested in hearing what you think!

Answer (score 1):

It is countably infinite.

Suppose that $A,B$, and $C$ are countably infinite sets. You already know that $A\times B$ is countably infinite. Depending on exactly how $A\times B\times C$ is defined, either it **is** $(A\times B)\times C$ by definition, in which case you already know that it is countably infinite as the Cartesian product of two countably infinite sets, or there is a trivial bijection between it and $(A\times B)\times C$, in which case you also know that it is countably infinite.

Comment: That makes complete sense.  Would the cartesian product written as (Z x Z x Z) be any different than (Z x Z) x Z (just looking at this as a set rather than a function)?

Comment: @HelloMath: In practical terms there is no difference. In formal terms it depends on exactly how one has defined $n$-tuples for $n>2$. Sometimes $3$-tuples $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ are defined to be $\langle\langle x,y\rangle,x\rangle$, in which case there is no difference at all. Sometimes they are defined as functions from $\{0,1,2\}$ such that $f(0)=x,f(1)=y$, and $f(2)=z$, in which case the two are actually different sets, though there is an obvious bijection between them. Unless one is doing formal set theory, this level of detail is ignored and they are considered to be the same set.

Comment: Right, sometimes the vector format is different depending on how one arranges the set.  So a set of Z x Z x Z should look something like {(1,2,3), (-1,2,-3), etc, etc, etc} such that this format of a cartesian product of three sets would still remain bijective, since one can apply both one-to-one and onto functions from Z x Z x Z to N x N x N as a proof?

Comment: @HelloMath: The fact that there is a bijection between $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is independent of exactly how ordered triples are formally defined. I could be wrong, but I suspect that you’ve not had any real exposure to formal set theory at the level at which ordered triples are given concrete definitions as sets. If so, you should simply follow normal everyday practice and consider $(A\times B)\times C$ the same set as $A\times B\times C$.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you.  I was wondering about the ordered triples because I had only been exposed to cartesian product of two sets.  I have no further education than a bachelor's in applied mathematics but found this question interesting.  Thank you for your time and insight!

Comment: @HelloMath: You’re welcome!